# how to show every values from input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im working on very simple chatbot on javascript

as you can see in example below, it does not work that show messages one under the other ,it replaces previous messages.

I want to show it one under the others

How can i show every input values in javascript

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/vl0DP

this is js codes

```
var questionNum = 0;
var mt = '<strong>BOT:</strong><br>';
var divr = '<div class="request">';
var divi = '</div>'                                                 // keep count of question, used for IF condition.
var question = mt+'What is your id?';                 // first question


var output = document.getElementById('AutoMessage');                // store id="output" in output variable
output.innerHTML = question;

var mes = document.getElementById('request');



                                                    // ouput first question

function bot() { 
    var input = document.getElementById("mesbox").value;
    console.log(input);

    if (questionNum == 0) {
    mes.innerHTML = divr  + input + divi;// output response
    document.getElementById("mesbox").value = "";           // clear text box
    question = mt+ 'how old are you?';                  // load next question       
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);                                    // output next question after 2sec delay
    }

    else if (questionNum == 1) {
    mes.innerHTML = divr+ input +divi;
    document.getElementById("mesbox").value = "";   
    question = mt+ 'where are you from?';                           
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);
    }  
     else if (questionNum == 2) {
    mes.innerHTML = divr +  input+divi;
    document.getElementById("mesbox").value = "";   
    question = mt+ 'is that good?';                           
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);
    }   
}

function timedQuestion() {
    output.innerHTML = question;
}

//push enter key (using jquery), to run bot function.
//push enter key (using jquery), to run bot function.
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    bot();                                                                                      // run bot function when enter key pressed
    questionNum++;                                                                      // increase questionNum count by 1
  }
   $(document).find('#chatBox').append(html);
      $(this).val('');
});
```

and the html

```
<div class="container">
<h4 class="display-4 text-center"> Very Simple Chatbot </h4>  
         <hr>

         <div class="chatBox" id="chatBox">

             <div class="response"><div id="AutoMessage"> <strong>bot:</strong> <br>Writing... </div></div>


            <div  id="request"></div>




                   <input class="w3-input" id="mesbox" type="text" placeholder="Mesajınızı buraya giriniz...">




         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the result you want is like this?

```js
var questionNum = 0;
var mt = '<strong>BOT:</strong><br>';
var divr = '<div class="request">';
var divi = '</div>'                                                 // keep count of question, used for IF condition.
var question = mt+'What is your id?';                 // first question


var output = document.getElementById('AutoMessage');                // store id="output" in output variable
output.innerHTML = question;

var mes = document.getElementById('request');



                                                    // ouput first question

function bot() { 
    var text="";
    var input = document.getElementById("mesbox").value;
    console.log(input);

    if (questionNum == 0) {
    text=mes.innerHTML;
    mes.innerHTML = text+divr+ input +divi;// output response
    document.getElementById("mesbox").value = "";           // clear text box
    question = mt+ 'how old are you?';                  // load next question       
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);                                    // output next question after 2sec delay
    }

    else if (questionNum == 1) {
    text=mes.innerHTML;
    mes.innerHTML = text+divr+ input +divi;
    document.getElementById("mesbox").value = "";   
    question = mt+ 'where are you from?';                           
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);
    }  
     else if (questionNum == 2) {
     text=mes.innerHTML;
    mes.innerHTML = text+divr +  input+divi;
    document.getElementById("mesbox").value = "";   
    question = mt+ 'is that good?';                           
    setTimeout(timedQuestion, 2000);
    }   
}

function timedQuestion() {
    output.innerHTML= question;
}

//push enter key (using jquery), to run bot function.
//push enter key (using jquery), to run bot function.
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    bot();                                                                                      // run bot function when enter key pressed
    questionNum++;                                                                      // increase questionNum count by 1
  }
  // $(document).find('#chatBox').append(html);
      $(this).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<h4 class="display-4 text-center"> Very Simple Chatbot </h4>  
         <hr>

         <div class="chatBox" id="chatBox">

             <div class="response"><div id="AutoMessage"> <strong>bot:</strong> <br>Writing... </div></div>


            <div  id="request"></div>




                   <input class="w3-input" id="mesbox" type="text" placeholder="Mesajınızı buraya giriniz...">




         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it is, but also auto messages too

Comment: just like a chat application